# is there any way to track web pages to be accessed after coming from a specific page only?

Tags: php

I want my login.php page to only be accessed after coming from index.php and not by directly entering "www.example.com/login.php". If there is any direct access to login.php, it should automatically get redirected to some 404 page or example.com. How to implement this?

Comment: Why would direct access be a problem? If people want to log in, why shouldn't they go there directly and save time?

Comment: You can't use the referrer header, as it can be easily forged.  Maybe try creating a short lived cookie or session variable from index.php and check that it exists when loading login.php. You can return a redirect using the `header` command or a different status code with `http_response_code` HTTP isn't really designed for this kind of flow.

Comment: why i was looking for this is so that people should be able to enter their firstly and then they should go to the login page and not directly going to login.php as it would create a blank username value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` like this:

```php
<?php
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    $whitelist = array(
      "www.example.com"
    );
    
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    // remove "http://" or "https://" from referer
    $referer = preg_replace('#^http(s)?://#', '', $referer);
    
    // check if referer registered in $whitelist
    if(!in_array($referer, $whitelist)){
      // show error 404
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }else{
      // do your code here or just do it below all of this code
    }
  }else{
    // show error 404
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  }
?>
```

Comment: so can i just write index.php and check for it in $whitelist = array("http://www.example.com") instead of the whole url?

Comment: Bear in mind that referer values can be spoofed fairly easily. So it's useful but you can't rely on it

Comment: I think you can @Dvsh, but the code will become a little complex. wait, I will try it first

Comment: @ADyson, I do the scraping things too, so I know too how to spoof it. Do have any idea to prevent it? :)

Comment: @HaniefHan you can't. If you're controlling the server, you're not in control of what is sent to you by the client. So you have to design your site in such a way that you might use this data for something non-essential (e.g. analytics) but that you don't rely on it for anything important (e.g. security).

Comment: @HaniefHan did you tried that? and did that worked out for you? please share the code if it did!

Comment: I have tried it, and it's works. 
I create 2 file `test.php` and `redirect.php`. Inside `test.php` is url `<a href="localhost/redirect.php">Access Redirect</a>`. I register `localhost/test.php` in whitelist file `redirect.php`. Can't access directly to `localhost/redirect.php` via browser, but it's works when I access via `test.php`